# How to get maven snapshot timestamp after "Deploy artifacts to Maven repository" to use in promotion

Tags: maven, jenkins

I have a CI Jenkins maven job with "Deploy artifacts to Maven repository" at the end as post build action.
Because I use SNAPSHOT version I would like to save the snapshot metadata inside the job build directories, so it create a link between jenkins BUILD_ID and maven SNAPSHOT timestamp.
Later when I promote a build the promote job can get the artifact from repository manager (nexus) using the metadata stored in the build directory.
How can I get the metadata (snapshotTimeStamp, snapshotBuildNumber,repositoryPath) of deployed artifacts in a specified build?